# add_action('wp_ajax_[action name]', myfunction) problem

Tags: hooks, actions, ajax

I'm trying to integrate ajax in wordpress using the wp codex guidelines.
In the PHP I added:

```
wp_enqueue_script ( 'my_ajax', ADMIN_URL . 'js/ajax.js','jquery','1.0.0' );
wp_localize_script( 'my_ajax', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

The ajax code is:

```
jQuery.ajax({url: MyAjax.ajaxurl, type: "POST",data: {action: 'myaction',postID : MyAjax.postID}, success: function(response) {
 alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
}});
```

and the PHP function that should be called by ajax is:

```
function ajax_function() {
...do something...
}
add_action('wp_ajax_myaction', 'ajax_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_admin_myaction', 'ajax_function');
```

The ajax call is successful (the "alert" works), however, the php function "ajax_function" is never called.
After doing some debugging I realized that even though the action call add_action('wp_ajax_ sets a new element in the global $wp_filter array, when the corresponding do_action runs inside admin-ajax.php, the $wp_filter array no longer contains that element.

Therefore, "ajax_function" function is ignored.
Any idea why the function is not called?

Comment: @user1567: You add the function to the `wp_ajax_myaction` and `wp_ajax_admin_myaction` hooks. Should that not be `wp_ajax_myaction` (for logged in users) and `wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction` (for anonymous users)?

Comment: yes I fixed it, thanks. By the way, I have an update_option call inside the "ajax_function" that seem to fail because it is called after all wordpress loading sequence is complete? Is there another way to update_option?

Answer (score 8):

In my projects I do it like that

PHP

```
function foo() {
    echo 'bar';
}
add_action('wp_ajax_foo', 'foo' ); // executed when logged in
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_foo', 'foo' ); // executed when logged out
```

Javascript

```
data = { action: 'foo', avalue: 'some value', 'anothervalue': 'another value' };
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
    alert(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know this guide, I went over it as well. I changed the function to be exactly like yours but no luck :-(
The function is still not called.

Comment: by the way, where do you set the value of ajaxurl variable?

Comment: In my example I assumed that variable is already set. In WP Backend the variable is always set. In the frontend I just define it in the header. <script type="text/javascript">
 var ajaxurl = <?php bloginfo('url') ?>'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
</script> I bet there is a smarter way to handle it.

Comment: I see. anyway, the function still doesn't work for me.
Does it matter that the ajax is for admin back end? or the same functions should be used?

Comment: I finally fixed it. The problem was the loading order and the location of the add_action calls.
I have another small question: you wrote
data = { action: 'foo', avalue: 'some value', 'anothervalue': 'another value' };
What if I want to include an array as the value of one of the keys?

Comment: Thats related to jQuery how you want to add Data for the ajax request. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ look for the examples, there are different ways how to inlcude data in the request.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the code:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_myfunc', 'prefix_ajax_add_myfunc' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_myfunc', 'prefix_ajax_add_myfunc' );

function prefix_ajax_add_myfunc() {
    // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response
}
```

and in your ajax call do this:

```
jQuery.post(
    ajaxurl, 
    {
        'action': 'add_myfunc',
        'data':   'foobarid'
    }, 
    function(response){
        alert('The server responded: ' + response);
    }
);
```

in the ajax call you'll call your function without `prefix_ajax_`. Only call by it's remaining. In that case it's `add_myfunc`. In the response it will send `done` if everything goes right. Else response will be `0` or `-1`.

Hope it will help. Thank you.